# Android Chromecast Sender won't update title and images

Tags: android, flutter, chromecast, google-cast, google-cast-sdk

I've followed the instruction from [Google](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/android_sender/integrate) on how to cast media metadata to chromecast, the initial loading is fine, it will show the title, image and play the stream, but my problem is that I am streaming a live audio stream and need to update the metadata from time to time without having to buffer the audio again.

---

This is a sample of my code:

```
    override fun loadMediaLoadRequestData(request: PlatformBridgeApis.MediaLoadRequestData?) 
    {
        if (request == null) return
        val remoteMediaClient: RemoteMediaClient = remoteMediaClient ?: return
        val mediaLoadRequest = getMediaLoadRequestData(request)
        remoteMediaClient.load(mediaLoadRequest)
    }

    fun getMediaLoadRequestData(request: PlatformBridgeApis.MediaLoadRequestData): MediaLoadRequestData {
        val mediaInfo = getMediaInfo(request.mediaInfo)

        return MediaLoadRequestData.Builder()
            .setMediaInfo(mediaInfo)
            .setAutoplay(request.shouldAutoplay)
            .setCurrentTime(request.currentTime)
            .build()
    }
    fun getMediaInfo(mediaInfo: PlatformBridgeApis.MediaInfo?): MediaInfo? {
        if (mediaInfo == null) return null

        val streamType = getStreamType(mediaInfo.streamType)
        val metadata = getMediaMetadata(mediaInfo.mediaMetadata)
        val mediaTracks = mediaInfo.mediaTracks.map { getMediaTrack(it) }
        val customData = JSONObject(mediaInfo.customDataAsJson ?: "{}")

        return MediaInfo.Builder(mediaInfo.contentId)
            .setStreamType(streamType)
            .setContentType(mediaInfo.contentType)
            .setMetadata(metadata)
            .setMediaTracks(mediaTracks)
            .setStreamDuration(mediaInfo.streamDuration)
            .setCustomData(customData)
            .build()
    }
```

---

Does anyone have any suggestion on how to modify **loadMediaLoadRequestData** in order to trigger the Chromecast receiver to update only the MediaMetadata and not have the stream buffer again?

Comment: As a sidenote I'm using the default media receiver app id CastMediaControlIntent.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APPLICATION_ID. Do I need to make a custom receiver for my issue?

Comment: Try updating on the receiver since the phone can become disconnected and the receiver should update itself as needed.